# How to create a custom sitemap of multiple subdomains?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, sitemap

how can I achieve a certain well structured layout in the Google search results as presented below? I am working with multiple WordPress instances on several sub domains (not a multisite). Google does not get along with the sitemap structure so all sites are scattered around.

In the search results it should look like this (basically like any other well structured sitemap):

EXAMPLE.COM
(Meta text)
---- SUB.EXAMPLE.COM
---- SUB.EXAMPLE.COM
---- SUB.EXAMPLE.COM

I messed around with Yoast but I did not reach any results.

Comment: Search results that look like that have nothing to do with sitemaps.